# Client Web Api em Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api

estou fazendo um client utilizando Web Api. O meu site tem a função server do Web Api. Encontrei essa referencia da Microsoft http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client que tem um exemplo de client:

```
static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // HTTP GET
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
        }...
```

O interessante é que na linha abaixo trava e morre:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
```

Procurando na internet, implementei este código que funciona:

```
static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:17694/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // HTTP GET
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Integracao/GetAllProducts/").Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var product = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var dados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TipoPessoa>>(product.Result);                     
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

A minha dúvida é, qual a grande diferença entre estes dois códigos. A minha implementação é aceitável?

Microsoft:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
```

Meu código:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Integracao/GetAllProducts/").Result;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A diferença principal é que a primeira opção (usando `await`) não irá bloquear o *thread* de onde ela for chamada (o compilador irá dividir o método, registrando um *callback* pra ser chamado quando o resultado da operação tiver disponível), enquanto a segunda (usando `.Result`) irá bloquear o *thread* até que a resposta chegue.

Se você executar o código com `.Result` no thread de UI (por exemplo, num método chamado quando um botão é pressionado), e a resposta do Web API demorar a chegar, a sua aplicação de Windows Forms irá parecer "travada" até que a resposta chegue.

Usar `.Result` funciona bem em aplicações de linha de comando, mas para aplicações com GUI usar `await` é recomendado.

Comment: descobri o motivo de await não funcionar no meu caso. No link da microsoft esta assim a chamada do evento:
`RunAsync().Wait();`. Se eu fizer `RunAsync();` funciona. Será que tem algo faltando. Outro detalhe do `RunAsync();`, o VS reclama: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call. E:\webapi\conversor\conversor\Form1.cs 43 13 conversor

Comment: Você pode fazer o método que chamou o `RunAsync()` ser assíncrono também (usando o modificador `async`), e com isso você poderá chamar `await RunAsync()`.